# Big for inside for. How can I reduce time?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, logic

I have 2 lists ("IDS" and "Pay"). The len of IDS is 50000 and the len of Pay is 650000
The IDS is a list of IDS, like [1,2,3,4,5,6 ... ] and the PAY list is a list of lists with all payment that the IDS did, like [ [1,50], [1,100], [1,60], [2,50], [2,80], [2,50], ...]

To know how much each ID payed in total, I'm doing a for loop inside another for loop like this one:

```
for x in IDS:
    total = 0
    for i in xrange(0,len(Pay)):
        if x == Pay[i][0]:
            total += Pay[i][1]
    print x + str(total)
```

But it is taking ages to process this!
I've tried to split Pay in 10 pieces, but still taking too long.
Anyone have some idea on how can I improve this operation?

Thank you!

Comment: use a dict for Pay {IDS: IDSmult} . ~O(1) instead of O(n)

Comment: What about using a dict for Pay? Like Pay = {1:[50,100,60]},2:[50,80,50,....

Comment: And if using a dict you could maybe also drop IDS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> pay = [ [1,50], [1,100], [1,60], [2,50], [2,80], [2,50]]
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for idx, amt in pay:
    c[idx] += amt
...     
>>> c
Counter({1: 210, 2: 180})
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about collections! But if the "pay" list have more infos, like the date of payment [1,50,2013-09-01] and I have to sum the values only of dates greater than '2013-01-01'?

Comment: @Antonio Just add an `if` condition: `for idx, amt, dt in pay: if dt >  2013-09-01:c[idx] += amt`. (Don't forget to convert the date string to datetime object using `datetime.datetime.strptime`.)

Comment: @Antonio: you should accept this solution if this works for you =D

Answer (score 2):

OK, the fact is you have 2 very long list. Instead of discuss on what library to use, what about a better algorithm?

IDs should naturally contains unique integers (my guess), while Pay is tuples of (id, payment).

Now think about where your list is coming from. There are two possibilities:

1. Read from file
2. From some database, like MySQL

If it is option 1, you should do the following instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict
totals = defaultdict(someObj_factory)
[totals[int(line.split[0])].accumulate(someObj_factory(line.split()[1]))
 for line in paymentFile]
```

First, you don't need the ids as an independent list, because you have them in Pay.

Second, it saves the reading time.

Third, for scripting language, list comprehension saves interpreting time.

Fourth, this is robust, as you can add any object you want, like date or tuples.

If it is option 2, do the counting in your database-.-

Another option is insert these into database, and do the counting there. MySQL etc. are designed for this kind of task. You will be surprise how efficient it is. More info: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

If `collections.Counter` doesn't work for you - say if you are on a different Python version, - converting your pay list to a dictionary will have the same effect.

```
totals = {}
for id, amount in pay:
   totals[id] = totals.setdefault(id, 0) + amount
```

> Like the date of payment [1,50,2013-09-01] and I have to sum the
>   values only of dates greater than '2013-01-01'?

Then do this:

```
import datetime

base_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2013-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d').date()

totals = {}
for idx, amount, pay_date in pay:
   if datetime.datetime.strptime(pay_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date() > base_date:
       totals[idx] = totals.setdefault(id, 0) + amount
```

Comment: Don't use `id` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to iterate over `Pay` once (rather than 50000 times!). You can drastically speed up your computation by hashing:

```
totals = dict(map(lambda id: (id,0), IDS))

for L in Pay:
    if L[0] in totals:
        totals[L[0]] = totals[L[0]] + L[1]


for (id, total) in totals.iteritems():
    print "id: %s, total: %d"%(id, total)
```

Comment: If `Pay[i][0]` for all `i` is in `IDS`, then you can further optimize by omitting the containment check, ie, `if L[0] in totals`.

Comment: Even if you could not hash, this manner of iteration is still superior because it likely maximizes cache hits.